# How to show layer attributes when mouse hovers on it with pyqgis?

Tags: pyqgis

My question is very clear. I want to show point features attributes when the mouse tool hovers on the feature. It can be like that:

[image]

If the mouse goes elsewhere the label should gone as well. And of course I know that the layer must be active layer for this.

Comment: I can not try anything because I even can not find it in QGIS 3.2

Comment: @MustafaUçar - You want to use something like **map tips** but activate it through PyQGIS?